# Is it normal that all components in Next.js are client components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I have a Next app. I use app folder and Next Auth library. So that each page has access to the session, I wrapped the entire application in a `SessionProvider`. But since it's `useContext` under the hood, I had to add the `'use client'` directive everywhere. This resulted in all pages being client-side since they use `useSession`. And all page components (buttons, inputs) also became client-side.

`app/layout.tsx`

```
const RootLayout = ({ session, children }: { session: Session; children: ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
                <html lang={`eng`} 
                    <head>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        {children}
                    </body>
                </html>
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}
```

some protected page

```
'use client';

import {useSession} from "next-auth/react";

export default function ProtectedPage() {
    const {data, status} = useSession()


    return (
                <div>
                    {status === "authenticated" ? <div>data.name</div> : null}
                </div>
    )
}
```

Is it normal that all pages and components are now rendered on the client? The Next Auth  documentation recommends wrapping everything in a provider, but then the main feature of Next.js, namely SSR, no longer works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal that all components in Next.js are client components?

Every component under the app folder is, by default, a server component, meaning that it's rendered on the server side, and its code stays on the server side.

With `use client`

> Is it normal that all pages and components are now rendered on the client?

You can mix server component in client component as its children.

```
<ClientComponent>
  <ServerComponent />
</ClientComponent>
```

For further detail, read [this article on dev.to](https://dev.to/zenstack/fun-with-nextjs-13-server-components-o37).

You may also be interested to read [this blog on medium](https://adhithiravi.medium.com/what-are-server-components-and-client-components-in-react-18-and-next-js-13-6f869c0c66b0).

Answer (score 2):

No, not every component needs to be a client component. You could create a wrapper component that is a client component which receives children. Both server and client components can be passed to client components as children.

###### Example wrapper component

```
"use client";

import NoAuthComponent from "components/NoAuthComponent";

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

// if the no auth view was provided as a prop rather then
// imported you could also make it a server component
export default function ProtectedView({ children }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const session = useSession();
  if (session?.status !== "authenticated") return <NoAuthComponent />;
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

###### Example usage

```
import "server-only";

import ProtectedView from "components/ProtectedView";
import MyServerComponent from "components/MyServerComponent";

export default async function MyPage(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const response = await fetch("...");
  const data = await response.json();
  return (
    <ProtectedView>
      <MyServerComponent data={data} />
    </ProtectedView>
  );
}
```

More information about composing, nesting and working with client and server components can be found inside the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#nesting-server-components-inside-client-components).